# Serving a binary protocol in .Net. Use WCF? IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I need to write a server that will handle a binary protocol with TLS.  Nothing to do with HTTP or SOAP.  But it needs to be able to accept incoming connections, with client certificates, maybe pooling, and provide responses.  Ideally could also post messages back to the client asynchronously but not a requirement.

Can this be done with a special IIS plug in?  or with WCF?  Or is it best done by just listening on a raw socket?

Edit.  To be clear, this is a binary protocol that is well defined by an industry standard.  I do not want any software to interpret it, package things into objects etc.  I just want to have a listener send bytes sent by a client to a class and then send them back.

Comment: sounds like you just want a WebSocket

Comment: Your best bet is probably to host in kestrel. Here's an example that serves "RESP" (i.e. pretends to be a redis server) while hosted in kestrel. Any use as an example? https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/toys/KestrelRedisServer - note Kestrel *should* also have full support for TLS without you needing to do much (I just didn't enable that, because RESP doesn't use TLS currently). Kestrel is also fully async aware, and is designed to use "pipelines" etc

Comment: @MichaelRandall WebSocket starts out as HTTP, so... probably not; sounds like a bespoke binary protocol

Comment: Is it possible that WCF over https with duplex communication could handle this?

Comment: @Marc Gravell Can Kestral work without HTTP. This is a binary protocol not so encapsulated.  In the Java space I hacked Jetty to do so, but it was messy.

Comment: @Tuntable yes, 100% it can *today*. But also the team responsible for Kestrel are actually abstracting the host into something called "generic host" *specifically* to make this distinction cleaner and more applicable to a range of applications. That is something for "next major", though. But for today: the link I already gave you *literally is that (non-http in Kestrel)* (RESP, i.e. redis, is nothing to do with http). Here's the direct links: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/toys/KestrelRedisServer/RedisConnectionHandler.cs and (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/toys/KestrelRedisServer/Program.cs#L16-L27 (the http server you can see on 5000 there is a *secondary* monitoring page, just to allow me to demo the server status conveniently)

Answer (score 0):

I think [Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting?view=netframework-4.7.2) can help you, you can make your own channel for example

Comment: I thought remoting was a COM like protocol.  Remember the bytes are their own protocol.